# "accounts for up to" vs "is gained from"

Tags: expressions, syntactic-analysis, phrase-usage, sentence-patterns

I am arguing with my colleague about what phrase is easier to understand, i.e. "accounts for up to" vs "is gained from". My wording is the following:

> Sometimes this sector accounts for up to 70% of GDP in developed countries.

My colleague insists that her sentence is much better and sounds more idiomatic for a native speaker for English as compared to my wording. Her version is the following:

> Almost 70% of GDP in developed countries is gained from this sector.

Is her version (= the last one) more natural for you? Did she formulate the idea in a better way?

The sentence was originally formulated in Russian and translated into English. The Russian sentence has the word that means "sometimes", i.e. it is not always the case. It happens from time to time

Comment: why do you have _sometimes_ in your sentence?

Comment: @ChongDogMillionaire the sentence was translated from Russian into English. The Russian sentence has the word that means "sometimes", i.e. it is not always the case. It happens from time to time.

Comment: Is it correct to use "sometimes" in this context? Does it sound natural with "sometimes" placed at the beginning of the sentence?

Comment: _Sometimes X happens_ is different from _X happens_.

Comment: GDP = gross domestic product. I don't think GDP is normally said to be *gained*. Your wording (*accounts for*) refers to the *composition* of GDP. It's more consistent with the part-whole relationship, so I'd consider it the better phrased of the two.

Comment: Using **gained** is not idiomatic. "Almost (As much as, Approximately) 70% of GDP in developed countries **comes from** this sector". There is no reason to use the passive voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the second, *gained from* is wrong in this context. You could try *due to*.

In the first, to my ear the more natural flow requires moving sometimes, and tweaking the wording:

> This sector sometimes accounts for as much as 70% of the GDP of developed countries.

Or, more succinctly,

> This sector can account for as much as 70% of a developed country's GDP.

Answer (score 0):

These are two entirely different ideas, and which is 'better' is a matter of which fits the facts, not which is more 'natural'. Grace is no substitute for accuracy.

Your sentence says that in developed countries the portion of GDP which this sector accounts for is in **some** cases as high as 70%; but you say nothing about how frequent these cases are, or what portion this sector accounts for in other cases. We have no way of knowing whether it is usually 65% or 60% or 50% or much lower—even nothing.

Your colleague's sentence says that in developed countries the portion of GDP which this sector accounts for is either in all cases or in the aggregate 70%; it's not clear which she means. If the former, we may assume that it **never** falls below 66% or 67%; if the latter, we can be fairly sure that it sometimes exceeds 70% and rarely falls much below, oh, 50% or 60%.

In either case, the choice between *accounts for* and *is gained from* is a matter of the theology of the particular econometric church you worship in. If you hold that "GDP" repesents the actual value of actual goods and services, then you may say *is gained from* or *is created in* or something of that sort. If you hold that "GDP" is a merely mathematical entity representing a mathematical operation on other mathematical entities—or if you're agnostic on the subject of the Real Presence—you're safer with *accounts for*.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the first sentence takes less time to understand, and I also agree with jimm101's alternate phrasings. I might say,

> "This sector can account for up to 70% of GDP in developed countries,"

just to keep your specific phrase in there, for argument's sake. Although, "up to" sort of already suggests the idea that 70% is the highest amount and it is sometimes lower, so perhaps you could just say,

> "This sector accounts for up to 70% of GDP in developed countries."